# Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'PRC0000001'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i keep getting this error, i dont know why, im still new to c#. kindly help me figure this out please. i have two dropdownlist that would populate data based on first dropdownlist selected value.

when i select a value on the first dropdownlist, i get that error..

here is my code..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //read sql server connection string from web.config file
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM emed_province ORDER BY PROVINCE_NAME ASC", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                adptr.Fill(dt);
            }

            ddlProvince.DataSource = dt;
            ddlProvince.DataTextField = "PROVINCE_NAME";
            ddlProvince.DataValueField = "PROVINCE_CODE";
            ddlProvince.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccreString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emed_province");

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT CITY_NAME FROM emed_city WHERE PROVINCE_CODE ="+ddlProvince.SelectedValue, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            adptr.Fill(dt);
        }

        ddlCity.DataSource = dt;
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CITY_NAME";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CITY_CODE";
        ddlProvince.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you can mark it solved by ticking the empty V icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you passed the raw value without quotes, so the database thought you mean field name.

Avoid this all mess by using Parameters:

```
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT CITY_NAME FROM emed_city WHERE PROVINCE_CODE=@pcode", conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", ddlProvince.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    adptr.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: it worked! but i have another problem, there is no data showing on the second dropdownlist after i selected a value on the first..

Comment: You're binding the wrong drop down. Change `ddlProvince.DataBind();` to `ddlCity.DataBind();` (in `ddlProvince_SelectedIndexChanged` method)

Comment: oops..!! that's my mistake.. sorry.. you're a great help.. wish i could add a + on you..

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an alternative approach, when using Parameters isn't viable.

The SQL interpreter is confusing values with database objects.
You can save the interpreter from confusion by making your SQL statement more explicit.  Surround columns and table names with `[` square brackets and wrap any values in single quotes.

```
    using (conn)
    {
        var whereValue = "'"+ddlProvince.SelectedValue+"'";//wrap in single quotes
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT [CITY_NAME] FROM [emed_city] WHERE [PROVINCE_CODE] = "+whereValue;
        SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        adptr.Fill(dt);
    }
```

The square brackets explicitly state to the SQL Intepreter that it is dealing with a database object.  The single quotes inform the interpreter it is dealing with a value.

Now the interpreter won't mistake your value for a column name.